# Function not Looping through all worksheet

Tags: html, css, excel, vba

I have this code.  It works fine except the WorksheetLoop() sub which only seem to run in the active sheet.  Here's my code.  It cleans HTML tag of CSS and changes some, then formats particular header tags to lowercase and proper case for countries.  I pieced the code together from different sources ctto.  And tweaked it to work the worksheets and apply the functions.  Except for one that seems to only apply to a single worksheet, the last subroutine.  Thoughts to improve and clean the code are welcome too

```
Sub Multi_FindReplace()
'Find & Replace a list of text/values throughout entire workbook from a table
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
Dim fndList As Integer
Dim rplcList As Integer

Dim myArray As Variant
Dim ReplaceCount As Long 'replaced cell counter

'Create variable to point to your table


'Create an Array out of the Table's Data
  Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange
  myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)

'Designate Columns for Find/Replace data
  fndList = 1
  rplcList = 2

'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 2)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook (skip sheet with table in it)
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> tbl.Parent.Name Then
 'counter for replaced cells
 ReplaceCount = ReplaceCount + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sht.Cells, "*" & fnd & "*")

          sht.Cells.Replace What:=myArray(fndList, x), Replacement:=myArray(rplcList, x), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

        End If
      Next sht
  Next x
  WorksheetLoop
MsgBox "It is cleaned, " & ReplaceCount & " cell(s)."
End Sub





Sub SearchHeaders()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("A:A")
' Define the pattern
Dim pattern As String: pattern = "*<h?>*</h?>*"
' Check each item against the pattern
    For Each cell In rng
        If (cell Like pattern = True) Then
        ' Debug.Print cell Like pattern
        ' Else
        ' Debug.Print "not"
            cell.Offset(0, 0).Value = cell.Value
            cell.Offset(0, 0).Value = joinCell(Capital(StripHTML(cell)), cell.Offset(0, 0).Value)
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub


Function StripHTML(cell As Range) As String
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")


    Dim sInput As String
    Dim sOut As String
    sInput = cell.Text


    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .pattern = "<[^>]+>" 'Regular Expression for HTML Tags.
    End With


    sOut = RegEx.Replace(sInput, "")
    StripHTML = sOut
    Set RegEx = Nothing
End Function

Function joinCell(Mainstring As String, Joinstring As String) As String
Dim string1, string2, fullstring As String
    string1 = Left(Joinstring, 4)
    string2 = Right(Joinstring, 5)
    joinCell = string1 & Mainstring & string2

End Function

Function Capital(ByVal s As String)
    Dim a, v As Variant, j As Long
    a = Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", _
"Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herrzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Côte d'Ivoire", "Cabo Verde", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czechia (Czech Republic)", "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Eswatini", "Ethiopia", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Holy See", "Honduras", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", _
"Kazakhstan", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar (formerly Burma)", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "North Korea", "North Macedonia", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Palestine State", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Qatar", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", _
"Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Korea", "South Sudan", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Timor-Leste", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States of America", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe")
    v = Split(s, " ")
    For j = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
        If StrComp(v(j), UCase(v(j)), vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then v(j) = StrConv(v(j), vbLowerCase)
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(v(j), a, 0)) Then v(j) = StrConv(v(j), vbProperCase)
    Next j
    Capital = Join(v, " ")
End Function

Sub WorksheetLoop()
Dim tb As ListObject
Set tb = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
Dim ws As Worksheet


    For Each ws In Worksheets
    'insert code here
     SearchHeaders
        If ws.Name <> tb.Parent.Name Then


            MsgBox ws.Name

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Sub SearchHeaders(ByVal ws as Worksheet)`... and within `SearchHeaders`, change `Set rng = Range("A:A")` to `Set rng = ws.Range("A:A")`

Comment: Hi, thanks, in the WorksheetLoop sub at the SearchHeaders it displayed a compile error: argument not optional.

Comment: Make that line `SearchHeaders ws`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is *unqualified* `Range` references, leading to an implicit `ActiveSheet`:

```
Sub SearchHeaders()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Range("A:A") ' you haven't qualified the worksheet the Range is on
```

Pass a worksheet as a parameter:

```
Sub SearchHeaders(ByVal ws as Worksheet)
    ...
    Set rng = ws.Range("A:A")
End Sub
```

Then when calling `SearchHeaders`:

```
SearchHeaders ws
```

or

```
SearchHeaders ws:=ws
```